# Unapplied curve modifier not applying after export?

Tags: modeling, game-engine, bones

This is my conveyor belt in game. its actually translating instead of rotating around the middle in a chainlike fashion, which it is doing in blender. I did this by moving the bone, and it rotates the chain. the curve is not applied, because i noticed if i apply it it will translate instead of rotating. how do i fix this?

[image]

this is what i want:

[image]

Comment: Does anyone have an answer?

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you need help with . . . ?

Comment: It's not import in. To unity correctly. Because i didn't apply the modifier, but when j apply it it stops doing the conveyor belt affect.

Comment: That is the expected behavior . . . you will need to find a way to animate it with all modifiers applied

Comment: Well how can i do that? Can you string a few gif's for me?

Comment: I don't know how, that is just what needs to be done. Your guess is as good as mine :/

Comment: well do you know how to rig a conveyor belt? No tutorials helped me

Comment: Sadly I do not :/ You will just have to experiment. If I think of a way I'll let you know

Comment: is there a reason my modifier is not appearing in unity if not applied in blender? i wish i could just fix this ive had this issue for 6 days.

Comment: All modifiers are applied when exported